# Craft 3 CP restriction

Tags: control-panel, security

How can I add an extra layer of authentication to cp in craft3? The client wants to add 2FA - I have been through the plugins with simpler restrictions, but these appear only for the front end. 2FA seems more like a Craft 4 feature to come right now.

Can `htpasswd` be used simply in a folder for admin?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Two-Factor Authentication plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/two-factor-authentication) available for Craft 3 and 4.
According to the documentation, this plugin can prevent users from accessing the Control Panel without having completed 2FA, so it seems like it's exactly what you're looking for.